# Cannot log events to Firebase DebugView from my Flutter FIrebase app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I want to use Firebase analytics to log events from my Flutter app into my Firebase project's DebugView.

I am using the example app from [this GitHub](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_analytics/example).

I have entered the Xcode parameters -FIRDebugEnabled  and -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled as shown [in this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/143)

I changed IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED in GoogleService-info.plist to true.

DebugView logging is not enabled.

Log events ARE going to Firebase because I can view them in StreamView.

I cannot get logs from my flutter app to be seen in Firebase / DebugView of my project.

- I went into XCode and added the two arguments noted above as directed from others who have got this working
- I changed IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED from false to true in GoogleService-Info.plist.
- I validated events were being published to Firebase because they appear in StreamView.

Comment: Having the same issue, not been able to fix it :(

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 9):

I searched and attempted most of the cases like you did and it didn't work too. But then I reset those changed and try only **-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled** and it does work for me.

I supposed you have set up and connect your project with firebase and follow example in [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics/example). Here what I do to enable debugview in Firebase Console.

- android: enable with this command

  `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.app_name`
- iOS

  add -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled to Product\Schema\Edit Schema

Hope this would help someone out there that still encounter this problem.

Comment: Apart from what @kimhak has answered, try uninstalling and reinstalling the application again

Comment: The device takes sometime to show up, more than an hour.

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter, the only thing that worked for me was *first* doing @Kimhak's solution:

1. Open XCode
2. In the top menu bar, click "Product"
3. Click "Scheme"
4. Click "Edit Scheme..."
5. Add the value `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` to the section "Run" with sub-header "Debug" underneath "Arguments Passed On Launch"
6. Click "Close" (it auto-saves your added value)

Then running in your Flutter project root:

```bash
flutter clean
```

```bash
flutter pub get
```

```bash
cd ios ; pod install
```

That solved it for me!